# Area read ActionListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

so I'm working on a basic program that makes an object move when I click. But the trick is to make it so the object doesn't move when I click in a certain area of the JFrame. So, the main question is this: In java, is there a way to have ActionListener not read a certain area of a JFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@Override 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());// clicked points in jframe

}
});
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!